Alternatives to luggage storage in IST, Turkey
I'm going to Turkey for work-related trip which is adjacent to my vacation. I'd like to leave somewhere my work equipment - a laptop and a phone while traveling elsewhere for 2-3 weeks. I'm planning to take return flight to my home country from IST airport as well as arrive there.
I'm thinking to use IST airport's luggage storage as suggested in some answers, but at the same time I'm not sure if it'd be the safest/appropriate option as some people expressed concerns and anecdotes on how unsafe this can be. Also, I'm willing to pay more for extra safety.
I'd love to hear other opinions on other options (again, for storing just the laptop and a phone) I can consider.

I don't have personal experience with luggage storage in Istanbul, but I would avoid the airport simply for the associated costs.
Here's an overview of options for luggage storage in Istanbul.

Thank you! If you happen to know how good these services are I'd love to hear your feedback.

I have no idea, sorry.
